# Flux aggregate function to calculate the difference from last to first

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I'm trying to learn the flux query language for InfluxDB. I'm using InfluxDB OSS 2.7.

I have a time-series with power usage from my power meter. It reports an ever increasing number in KWh, and I want to show how many Wh I have used per day, by using a custom function with `aggregateWindow`. Here is what I have tried:

```
myFunc = (tables=<-, column) => {
  a = tables
    |> first(column: column)
    |> findRecord(fn: (key) => true, idx: 0)

  b = tables
    |> last(column: column)
    |> findRecord(fn: (key) => true, idx: 0)

  d = b._value - a._value

  return tables
    |> first()
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _value: d}))
}

from(bucket: "a")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "el")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "ACTIVE_IMPORT")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: myFunc, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "Wh")
```

But this returns a new table, where all `_value` have the same number (in my case 134).

I was hoping that the variables `a` and `b` would have the first and the last value of each *window*, and that `d` would represent the usage in each window - but this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find for each window the difference between the first and last values you can use the [`spread` function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/spread/).
To be precise `spread` calculates the difference between the minimum and maximum values (not first and last) but in an always-increasing series the two are the same.

This though is not precise. If you consider the following data:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-12T00:00:00Z | 100 |
| 2023-04-12T01:00:00Z | 101 |
| 2023-04-12T02:00:00Z | 102 |
| 2023-04-12T03:00:00Z | 103 |
| 2023-04-12T04:00:00Z | 104 |
| 2023-04-12T05:00:00Z | 105 |
| 2023-04-12T06:00:00Z | 106 |
| 2023-04-12T07:00:00Z | 107 |
| 2023-04-12T08:00:00Z | 108 |
| 2023-04-12T09:00:00Z | 109 |
| 2023-04-12T10:00:00Z | 110 |
| 2023-04-12T11:00:00Z | 111 |
| 2023-04-12T12:00:00Z | 112 |
| 2023-04-12T13:00:00Z | 113 |
| 2023-04-12T14:00:00Z | 114 |
| 2023-04-12T15:00:00Z | 115 |
| 2023-04-12T16:00:00Z | 116 |
| 2023-04-12T17:00:00Z | 117 |
| 2023-04-12T18:00:00Z | 118 |
| 2023-04-12T19:00:00Z | 119 |
| 2023-04-12T20:00:00Z | 120 |
| 2023-04-12T21:00:00Z | 121 |
| 2023-04-12T22:00:00Z | 122 |
| 2023-04-12T23:00:00Z | 123 |
| 2023-04-13T00:00:00Z | 124 |
| 2023-04-13T01:00:00Z | 125 |
| 2023-04-13T02:00:00Z | 126 |
| 2023-04-13T03:00:00Z | 127 |
| 2023-04-13T04:00:00Z | 128 |
| 2023-04-13T05:00:00Z | 129 |
| 2023-04-13T06:00:00Z | 130 |
| 2023-04-13T07:00:00Z | 131 |
| 2023-04-13T08:00:00Z | 132 |
| 2023-04-13T09:00:00Z | 133 |
| 2023-04-13T10:00:00Z | 134 |
| 2023-04-13T11:00:00Z | 135 |
| 2023-04-13T12:00:00Z | 136 |
| 2023-04-13T13:00:00Z | 137 |
| 2023-04-13T14:00:00Z | 138 |
| 2023-04-13T15:00:00Z | 139 |
| 2023-04-13T16:00:00Z | 140 |
| 2023-04-13T17:00:00Z | 141 |
| 2023-04-13T18:00:00Z | 142 |
| 2023-04-13T19:00:00Z | 143 |
| 2023-04-13T20:00:00Z | 144 |
| 2023-04-13T21:00:00Z | 145 |
| 2023-04-13T22:00:00Z | 146 |
| 2023-04-13T23:00:00Z | 147 |

Then if you take the spread in each day you will get:

```
from(bucket: "a")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "el")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "ACTIVE_IMPORT")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: spread, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "Wh")
```

| day | first | last | spread |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-13T00:00:00Z | 100 | 123 | 23 |
| 2023-04-13T00:00:00Z | 124 | 147 | 23 |

The actual consumption for each day, instead is 24. By using spread you are missing one interval for each day (the consumption from 123 to 124 is never accounted). Of course if your data has higher granulatiry (e.g.: every minute or every second) the missing value will be a lot less significant.

To solve this I would suggest just getting a single value for each day (the last) and then using the [`difference` function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/difference/#Copyright). This will then do a "rolling difference" so subtract to each value the previous one and will give you a better result (all hours will be accounted for).

```
from(bucket: "a")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "el")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "ACTIVE_IMPORT")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
  |> difference()
  |> yield(name: "Wh")
```

Aggregating with `last` will give:

| day | last |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-13T00:00:00Z | 123 |
| 2023-04-13T00:00:00Z | 147 |

Then applying `difference` will result in:

| day | difference(last) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-13T00:00:00Z |  |
| 2023-04-13T00:00:00Z | 24 |

> NOTE: the first value will be null since it does not have anything before it to di the `difference` with